# Flask: jsonify listed generator

Tags: python, json, flask, generator, jsonify

I'm using flask to jsonify a generator that has been listed using the `list()` command inside a dictionary like so:

```
r = {
      "stocks": list(current_user.stocks)
     }
```

But when I try to use `jsonify(r)` I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type Stocks is not JSON serializable

In the terminal, if I just print out `list(current_user.stocks)`, it returns me:

```
[<Stocks GOOGL>, <Stocks TSLA>]
```

Stocks is a table/class i'm using in flask-sqlalchemy. I want the JSON to look something like this:

```
{"stocks": [<Stocks GOOGL>, <Stocks TSLA>]}
```

I have no problem with `<Stocks GOOGL>` and the other array element being a string.

Any ideia as to how to jsonify this inside a dict? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `Stocks`? How do you want it to look like? Please provide the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is not a valid JSON. You can try something like:

```
r['stocks'] = list(map(repr, r['stocks']))
```

Then `jsonify(r)` should produce something like:

```
{"stocks": ["<Stocks GOOGL>", "<Stocks TSLA>"]} # Note that these are strings
```